# MySQL sum values of a row

Tags: sql, mysqli

This query add user points for g1 and g2, I would like to insert the sum of these 2 values in another column called 'total_points'. I realized I can't use SUM(), because they're many columns but just one row. 
What's the best way to do this?
I currently have this query:

```
 $query = "UPDATE `points` SET g1 = $g1 + 10, g2 = $g2 + 10 WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Assuming I have this values:

```
$g1 = '50'; $g2 = '25';
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend calculating the field when you query for it, rather than storing it in the table.

```
SELECT g1, g2, g1 + g2 AS Total FROM points
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store a calculable value in your database... calculate them when you query for it:

```
SELECT g1, g2, g1 + g2 as total_points FROM points
```